# Desativar autocomplete Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Boa tarde pessoal!

entrei no mundo da programação recentemente e me disseram que começar a programar sem esses suportes de autocomplete é melhor agora no início. O que vocês acham?

Dito isso gostaria de uma ajudinha a desativar essa função no Pycharm, tentei de varias formas e pesquisar em varios lugares. Não encontrei nada em PT e não manjo mt inglês...

Agradeço desde já galera! Bora programar!!!

Comment: Dicas: Faça apenas uma pergunta por post e evite perguntas especulativas como "o que vc acha".

Comment: Com ou sem autocomplete estude o que cada método, classe, função faz, ai com auto complete ou sem você vai aprender, se fizer sem autocomplete e não estudar, viver só de copiar e colar, não vai fazer diferença, vocÊ vai estagnar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desligue "Show suggestions as you type", ele vai parar de exibir sugestões automaticamente. Mesmo com esta opção desligada você ainda pode usar Ctrl+Espaço para ver as sugestões se desejar.

[image: Settings do pycharm]

Answer (score 0):

Eu também discordo sobre isso. Quanto mais prático e facilitado pra vc eh melhor. Existem coisas que a própria IDLE não só te lembra, como também te mostra outras possibilidades que você não viu com seu professor (muitas coisas inclusive) ou na própria documentação por exemplo.

> Um exemplo simples sobre a função `int()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Um exemplo simples sobre a função `print()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você não eh obrigado a saber de tudo, não conheço ninguém que seguiu por esse caminho..

Mas se vc quer de fato esse caminho então você não precisa de um IDLE como Pycharm ou qualquer Editor de Texto (Sublime, VS Code..), você pode usar a própria do Python que não tem essas facilidades, eh só criar um novo arquivo e vai ter o arquivo de texto padrão que vem com a instalação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo da esquerda eh o que aparece quando vc clica no IDLE Python (que está circulado de vermelho)
Para usar o editor padrão eh só criar um novo arquivo (como está mostrando) e pronto..
Pra executar seu código eh só apertar F5 (salva automaticamente) que aparece no arquivo da esquerda a execução

Answer (score -1):

Sinceramente eu discordo dessa ideia. Realmente você vai fixar melhor alguns comandos, mas muitas vezes pra você verificar o tipo do objeto a função de autocomplete é muito boa. Eu comecei a estudar Python a pouco tempo e acho que isso me ajudou muito.

Um exemplo, ao declarar uma lista:

```
UmaLista = list()
UmaLista. #Nesse momento o autocomplete te sugere todas as funções
          #exclusivas de uma lista, como append, pop, remove etc.

palavra = 'a.b.c.d.e'
palavra. #Nesse momento o autocomplete sugere todas as funções de
         #uma string como split, replace e etc.
```

Uma prática boa pra se desenvolver no começo é não copiar e colar códigos que você usa frequentemente. É melhor sempre digitá-los novamente para que você consiga fixar a lógica ou os conceitos básicos.